# How to get DDL for procedure and triggers in IBM UDB DB2

Tags: db2

Can someone please help me to extract DDL for procedure and triggers  using db2look command in IBM UDB DB2

Answer (score 0):

You can't extract ddl of a single SP or trigger with [db2look](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-db2look-db2-statistics-ddl-extraction-tool).
Use `-e` along with some non-default statement terminator like `@` to extract either all of them (`-a`) or belonging to some specific schema name (`-z`).
DDL for trigger on tables is extracted with `-t` or `-tw` options as well.
Refer to the link above for more details on db2look and its options.

```
db2look -d dbname -td @ -e [-a | -z schema] ...
```